# How to upload and retreive PDF files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am doing a project on VB.NET for learning purpose. It's a desktop application with MS SQL server as backend. One of the module is to upload and view PDF documents. I have searched over internet and found that it can be done in two ways, either storing the PDF directly into database or in a directory. I was able to save the document in database but I do not know how to display it within the application.

I am using **AxAcroPDF component** for display purpose. I came across some websites which said that PDF stored in database cannot be displayed through the AcroPDF but if the files are saved in directory then they can be displayed via file path. If thats the case, I would like to know how to save PDF in directory.

Now, these PDF docs are as per some categories like

```
Type A will have 4 associated PDF, 
Type B will have 5 or 6 associated PDFs.
```

I don't want to mix up all PDF together in single directory. Is it possible while uploading, a folder can be created dynamically and a PDF associated to the type are saved in that particular folder? So, it will be easier to view PDF of particular type only and not all of the uploaded docs.
But this all will be required if PDF stored in database cannot be viewed by AcroPDF.

I am storing PDF in database as **varbinary**.

Answer (score 0):

Imports AxAcroPDFLib Imports AcroPDFLib

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    AxAcroPDF1.Location.Equals(AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile("C:\path\file.pdf"))
    AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile("C:\path\file.pdf")
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```